# NSURLConnection fails sometimes - Server inaccessible?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

How can I detect if an NSURLConnection failure is due to server being inaccessible?

I checked the server's logs and there is no mention of the app's calls in these cases when the NSURLConnection failed. However, could it be that trying to initiate the NSURLConnection (see below) failed for a different reason?

I implement the call to NSURLConnection via a wrapper with the following init function:

```
-(id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)url
        postData:(NSData*)postData
    responseData:(NSMutableData*)responseData
        delegate:(id)delegate
    doneSelector:(SEL)doneSelector
   errorSelector:(SEL)errorSelector {

    if(self=[super init]) {
        _url = [url retain];
        _postData = [postData retain];
        _responseData = [responseData retain];
        _delegate = [delegate retain];
        _doneSelector = doneSelector;
        _errorSelector = errorSelector;

        // Set up request
        NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
        [request setURL:_url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[_postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:_postData];

        // Kick off the connection
        NSURLConnection* connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
        if(!connection) {
            [_delegate performSelector:_errorSelector];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

We never encountered this problem during our testing (and 99% of the time the URL connection works flawlessly for our users) so I am unable to say where exactly the NSURLConnection fails. I do know though that when it fails the `errorSelector` is called with an empty `_responseData` string.

Do you see anything in the above code that may fail on rare occasions?

Any idea how to find the cause of the connection failures?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you implement `connection:didFailWithError:` and let iOS tell exactly why it failed?

Comment: Thank you @Avi, this sounds like a very reasonable idea.

Comment: If  `initWithRequest` fails and the returned connection is nil, how can I find the error message? (I assume the `didFailWithError` event can be triggered only when the transfer is underway).